# Train Word Embeddings on new vocabulary given the pre trained embeddings through word2vec

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have the pre-trained Embbedings on the language. I have the vocabulary for that language, what would be the pipeline to train this vocabulary by using Pre train embeddings through the word2vec model?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a word2vec fine-tuning?

If yes, here is a guide on how to do it:

https://czarrar.github.io/Gensim-Word2Vec/

See also:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/rtatman/fine-tuning-word2vec/notebook

Comment: I have pre-train word embeddings  from this link

[link](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/2020/12/01/urduvec_140M_300d_ur.html)

and the vocabulary of the language  with unique words,
 
do I need to train it again on the vocabulary? or is it possible to train it again?

Comment: Do you mean with a new vocabulary in addition to the existing one?

Comment: I would say the vocabulary is going to same because that contains the dictionary of the particular language. Do we still need to train it again, or I can compute the embeddings using the pre-train embeddings?

Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: Thank you I only need to compute the embeddings through the pre-trained embeddings  The fine tune i required when the data is new or of other language, I am new to NLP that's why

Comment: That's why fine-tuning seems more appropriate: you reuse the model already trained, and you train it again with new data. The links above should do the job.